# Looping through element in Pig to generate a new tuple for relation

Tags: apache-pig

Say I have a relation as follow:

```
(A, (1, 2, 3))
(B, (2, 3))
```

Is it possible to make a new relation by expanding the bag element as follow using Pig Latin?

```
(A, 1)
(A, 2)
(A, 3)
(B, 2)
(B, 3)
```

I tried using `FOREACH` and `GENERATE`, but I am having difficulty generating a new tuple while looping through a bag element.

Thanks,

**-------------**
**EDIT**
**-------------**

Here's a sample input:

```
A    1 2 3
B    2 3
```

Separated by tab and then a whitespace.

I used `STRSPLIT` to handle whitespace to generate a tuple.

```
raw_x = LOAD './sample.txt' using PigStorage('\t') AS (title:chararray, links:chararray);
data_x = FOREACH raw_x GENERATE title, STRSPLIT(links, '\\s+') AS links;
```

Comment: Its looks like your tuple fields are not in fixed length. Can you paste your pig script and sample input?

Comment: Yes, the tuple fields are not in fixed length. I added sample input and script. I'm guessing maybe I should take a different approach to handle this case? Any form of suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Updated the solution,please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input.txt**

```
A       1 2 3
B       2 3
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (title:chararray,links:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE title,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(links));
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(A,1)
(A,2)
(A,3)
(B,2)
(B,3)
```